# Examples on primitive and boxed version of primitives in Clojure

Tags: clojure, primitive

What are the places in which Clojure uses Java primitives as is and uses the boxed versions of the primitives?

As I see [here](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Numbers), it is mentioned that Clojure provides full support for primitives. Is there any clear definition on when and where primitives and boxed versions are used in Clojure?

Comment: I think it is fair to say that the Clojure reference does use an amount of ‘marketing speak’ sort of statements. It would be more correct to say ‘Clojure provides *limited* support for JVM primitives’. Boxing is certainly the default behaviour when passing around values. The [interop page](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#primitives) has some more info.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the rules for when Clojure uses unboxed math can be easily summarized in a few lines (but I may be wrong). But you can use [clj-java-decompiler](https://github.com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-java-decompiler) to decompile Clojure code into Java code to get an idea about what goes regarding boxing and unboxing. If I evaluate this code

```clj
(ns playground.decompile
  (:require [clj-java-decompiler.core :as d]))

(d/decompile
 (loop [product 1
        counter 10]
   (if (= 0 counter)
     product
     (recur (* product counter)
            (dec counter)))))
```

it prints out this code

```java
// Decompiling class: playground/decompile$fn__7159
package playground;

import clojure.lang.*;

public final class decompile$fn__7159 extends AFunction
{
    public static Object invokeStatic() {
        long product = 1L;
        long multiply;
        for (long counter = 10L; 0L != counter; counter = Numbers.dec(counter), product = multiply) {
            multiply = Numbers.multiply(product, counter);
        }
        return Numbers.num(product);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke() {
        return invokeStatic();
    }
}
```

Here, it looks to me as if the compiler understands that we are using `long` numbers. You probably have to look from case to case whether boxing happens or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good information on Java interop re primitive types here:

- https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#typehints

You may also be interested in this library for working with primitive arrays:

- https://github.com/plumatic/hiphip